# Does indentation matter in django?

Tags: python, django, django-templates

Template file:

```
{% if object.name== '' %}
    {% block name %}{{ object.name}}{% endblock name %}
       {% else %}
            {% block name %} {{ object.alternate_name}} 
            {% endblock name %}
           {% endif %}
```

I have this code in Django and for some reason, I get the error that the block name has been repeated twice and that seems impossible because they're inside an `if-else` statement. However, I realized my indentation looks like it did above. I'm not sure whats causing this.

Answer (score 1):

You can not make blocks conditional: these are nodes that are directly at the level of `{% extends %}`. You can move the condition into the block:

```
{% block name %}
  {% if object.name == '' %}
    {{ object.name}}
  {% else %}
    {{ object.alternate_name}} 
  {% endif %}
{% endblock name %}
```

that being said, the condition should probably be reversed. You can also probably use [**`{% firstof … %}`** <sup>[Django-doc]</sup>](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/stable/ref/templates/builtins/#firstof):

```
{% block name %}
    {% firstof object.name object.alternate_name %}
{% endblock name %}
```

Comment: Thankyou guys so much! That was the reason it kept breaking

Answer (score 0):

To fix the issue, you can remove the duplicate block definition and move the contents of the if-else statement into a single block definition.

Try this:

```py
{% block name %}
    {% if object.name == '' %}
        {{ object.name }}
    {% else %}
        {{ object.alternate_name }}
    {% endif %}
{% endblock name %}
```